# How do I use AND operator in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

How do I use AND operator in Robot Framework
Below code gives error as - > No keyword with name 'and' found.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Purchase Items
    Pre Condition
    Login With Valid User
    Run Keyword If  '${price}' > '$29.99'   Purchase Items greater than $30.00
    ...  ELSE IF    '${price}' < '$29.99'   and   '${price}' > '$20.00'  Purchase Items less than $30.00
    ...  ELSE IF    '${price}' == '$29.99'  Purchase Items less than $30.00
    ...  ELSE   Not Enough Amount to Purchase
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only a single space before and after `and`

```
...  ELSE IF    '${price}' < '$29.99' and '${price}' > '$20.00'  Purchase Items less than $30.00
```

Comment: ......Thanks, It Worked